# Loading an Unencrypted PEM Public Key with OpenSSL libcrypt

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, openssl, pem, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to load a `SECP256R1` Public Key that I've created with OpenSSL into my C program. According to [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/pem_password_cb.html) the code below should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

int main()
{
    EC_KEY *pk = NULL;
    FILE *in = fopen("pk.pem", "rt");

    if (!in)
        return 2;

    pk = PEM_read_EC_PUBKEY(in, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

However, before returning from the `PEM_read...` call my program suddenly exits with a `1` code, with no further explanation. What can be the cause of this?

pk.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEGQxkTNnZ3zp4NXgpnwhTkU2fzENB
RPXu3JJq1gx/CwZGh4mIWPbmHvd8eYUmffoPu4fPU6UxAQwGIH7+DEaKJw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

sk.pem:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIElzeIrCIus5+2GIayg/i7VubOCQ1yqApAo2sau4dD1hoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEGQxkTNnZ3zp4NXgpnwhTkU2fzENBRPXu3JJq1gx/CwZGh4mIWPbm
Hvd8eYUmffoPu4fPU6UxAQwGIH7+DEaKJw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: `if (!in) return 1;` would result in a 1 code with no further explanation. Is the file in the working directory of your program?

Comment: Yes. The `PEM_read...` call is made.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: @Olaf Nothing... I can't even Step Into it. Maybe I should try and build OpenSSL myself instead of downloading prebuilt binaries?

Comment: @Olaf It means that when I press "Step Into" (F11 in Visual Studio), it doesn't step into the function. That happens when a binary doesn't have a Debug Database (.pdb in Windows) shipped with it. A non-annotated function is considered atomic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem vanished simply by adding `#include <openssl/applink.c>` at the top.
It's an issue with using OpenSSL on Windows, apparently.